# Como puedo unir 2 listas que se relacionen por la propiedad Id?

Tags: c#, lista, foreach

Tengo dos listas con una estructura similar a la siguiente:

```
var secciones = [{IdSeccion = 1, IdPresupuesto = 30, TituloSeccion = "Albañilerias"},
                 {IdSeccion = 2, IdPresupuesto = 30, TituloSeccion = "Aplanados"},
                 {IdSeccion = 3, IdPresupuesto = 30, TituloSeccion = "Estructuras"}];


var conceptos = [{Id = 41, IdSeccion = 1, IdPresupuesto = 30, Concepto = "Concepto de prueba Uno"},
                 {Id = 42, IdSeccion = 1, IdPresupuesto = 30, Concepto = "Concepto de prueba Dos"},
                 {Id = 43, IdSeccion = 1, IdPresupuesto = 30, Concepto = "Concepto de prueba Tres"},
                 {Id = 44, IdSeccion = 1, IdPresupuesto = 30, Concepto = "Concepto de prueba Cuatro"},
                 {Id = 45, IdSeccion = 2, IdPresupuesto = 30, Concepto = "Concepto de prueba Cinco"}]
```

y quiero obtener algo similar a esto: una lista con una sub lista de objetos.

```
[{
    "Id":1,
    "IdPresupuesto": 30,
    "Titulo": "Albañilerias",
    "ConcepList":[{Id = 41, IdSeccion = 1, IdPresupuesto = 30, Concepto = "Concepto de prueba Uno"},
                 {Id = 42, IdSeccion = 1, IdPresupuesto = 30, Concepto = "Concepto de prueba Dos"},
                 {Id = 43, IdSeccion = 1, IdPresupuesto = 30, Concepto = "Concepto de prueba Tres"}]
},
{
    "Id":2,
    "IdPresupuesto": 30,
    "Titulo": "Aplanados",
    "ConcepList":[{Id = 44, IdSeccion = 2, IdPresupuesto = 30, Concepto = "Concepto de prueba Cuatro"},
                 {Id = 45, IdSeccion = 2, IdPresupuesto = 30, Concepto = "Concepto de prueba Cinco"}]
},
{
    "Id":3,
    "IdPresupuesto": 30,
    "Titulo": "Estructuras",
    "ConcepList": null
}]
```

Estoy usando un foreach par llenar mi lista pero no se como poder hacer la relación con mi IdSeccion de mis listas para que los elementos de mi nueva lista (List < DataListConcepts > ) se agreguen a una sublista de objetos.

```
public class DataListConcepts {
        public int Id { get; set; } 
        public string Titulo { get; set; }
        public int IdPresupuesto { get; set; }
        public IList<Conceptos> ConcepList { get; set; }
    }   

List<DataListConcepts> data = new List<DataListConcepts>();

    foreach (var itemSeccion in secciones)
    {

        foreach (var itemConcepto in conceptos)
        {

            DataListConcepts seccionesList = new DataListConcepts()
            {
                Id = itemSeccion.IdSeccion,
                Titulo = itemSeccion.TituloSeccion,
                IdPresupuesto = itemSeccion.IdPresupuesto,
                ConcepList = new List<Conceptos>()
                {
                    new Conceptos(){
                    Id = items.Id,
                    Concepto = items.Concepto,
                    IdSeccion = items.IdTituloSeccion,
                    IdPresupuesto = items.PresupuestoId
                    }
                }
            };
            data.Add(seccionesList);
        }
    }
```

y claramente mi foreach me da un resultado NO deseado, ya que obtengo una lista de 15 elementos

De que forma podría agregar mis elementos a mi sublista relacionandolos por mi IdSeccion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes lograrlo usando Linq de la siguiente forma:

```
var result = secciones.Select(s => new
        {
            Id = s.IdSeccion,
            s.IdPresupuesto,
            Titulo = s.TituloSeccion,
            ConcepList = conceptos.Where(c => c.IdSeccion.Equals(s.IdSeccion) )
        });
```

Comment: Si, muchas gracias, ya lo pude resolver, aplicando la misma idea pero de distinta forma.

Comment: Elegante, Miguel.

Answer (score 0):

pues al final lo pude resolver de la siguiente forma.

```
 List<DataListConcepts> dataList = new List<DataListConcepts>();

                foreach (var item in sections)
                {
                    DataListConcepts seccionesList = new DataListConcepts()
                    {
                        Id = item.Id,
                        Titulo = item.TituloSeccion,
                        IdPresupuesto = item.IdPresupuesto,
                        ConcepList = _concepts.GetConceptListByTitleSectionId(item.Id).Result
                    };
                    dataList.Add(seccionesList);
                }
```